# Sine series simplification to get rid of the factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to rewrite sine series in a way to get rid of the factorial.

$$\begin{array}{c c c c c} 
 sin(x) & x & -\ {x^3 \over 3!} & +\ {x^5 \over 5!} & -\ {x^7 \over 7!}\\ 
 & T_0 & T_1 & T_2  & T_3\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
If we number the terms from $0$ onward. I chose $3rd$ term over $2nd$ term to further simplify.

$$
\begin{align}
 {T_3 \over T_2} & = {-{x^7 \over 7!} \over {x^5 \over 5!}} \\
 {T_3 \over T_2}  &= -{x^7 \over 7!}\  \cdot {5! \over x^5 } \\
 T_3 & = -T_2 \ . \  {x^2 \over 7 \ \cdot 6}
\end{align}
$$

But I wanna generalize it for $i$ so I eventually end up with something like this:

$$ 
^{(*)} \ \  T_i = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot {x^2 \over (2i+1) \ 2i}
$$
so that I can write it down programmatically in a recurrent algorithm:
$$ 
 T = -T * (x*x)/(2i+1)/2i
$$
(-- from now on, it's magic that I'm not sure is correct --)

Problem is, when I get to the
$$
 T_i = - T_{i-1} \cdot {x^{2i+1} \over (2i+1)!}\ \cdot {(2i-1)! \over x^{2i-1} } \\
 \text{for $i = 3$ from the $T_3$}
$$
I don't know how to simplify from here. I know I need to end up with $^{(*)}$, but don't know how.

Ideas?

---

Solution from Jacob's hint:

$$
\begin{align}
T_i & = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot   {x^{(2i+1)-(2i-1)} \over (2i+1)!}\ \cdot {(2i-1)! \over 1 } \\
T_i & = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot  {x^{2} \over (2i+1)((2i+1)-1)!}\ \cdot {(2i-1)! \over 1 } \\
T_i & = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot  {x^{2} \over (2i+1)(2i)!}\ \cdot {(2i-1)! \over 1 } \\
T_i & = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot  {x^{2} \over (2i+1)(2i)(2i-1)!}\  \cdot {(2i-1)! \over 1 } \\
T_i & = -\ T_{i-1} \cdot  {x^{2} \over  (2i+1)(2i)}\  \cdot {1 \over 1 }
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Just a remark: typesetting $X.-Y$ without parentheses looks quite badly (and many people consider it wrong and undefined). You can try `X\cdot\left(-Y\right)` with the output: $$X\cdot\left(-Y\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(2i+1)!=(2i+1)(2i)(2i-1)!$ and $x^{2i+1}/x^{2i-1}=x^2$.

Comment: Now I realized how easy it is! Going to update with your solution.